# Ошибка при установке laravel/homestead для vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Недавно я решил изучить Laravel и для работы с ним и мне понадобился homestead.
Я нашел инструкцию по установке
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BM72cuBKtM и следовал ей.

На 16 шаге при попытке поднять vagrant выдает ряд ошибок.

```
    /home/wolf/Homested/scripts/homestead.rb:138: syntax error, unexpected tPOW
...ype: folder["type"] ||= nil, **options
...                               ^
/home/wolf/Homested/scripts/homestead.rb:149: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
      settings["sites"].each do |site|
                               ^
/home/wolf/Homested/scripts/homestead.rb:191: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
        settings["databases"].each do |db|
                                     ^
/home/wolf/Homested/scripts/homestead.rb:192: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
          config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
                               ^
/home/wolf/Homested/scripts/homestead.rb:192: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
          config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
                                        ^
/home/wolf/Homested/scripts/homestead.rb:202: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

К сожалению я мне не понятен синтаксис данного конфигурационного файла Vagrant

Сам файл содержит следующую информацию:

```
    require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end

    if defined? VagrantPlugins::HostsUpdater
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end
end
```

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно заполнить и исправить, чтобы поднять vagrant для homestead.

Comment: Видеоуроку уже почти год, хм. Похоже, что код выполняется на слишком старом Ruby, в котором ещё нет "хэш-остатка" (**). Что выводит `ruby -v`?

Comment: У меня ruby 2.0 со вчерашнего дня. Попробовал. Потом поставил еще 2.3. Однако не работает.